# How to keep DataFrame.to_csv() from adding line breaks for list values in cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have this minimal example:

```
import tempfile

tempdir = tempfile.gettempdir()
test_output = tempdir + '/test.csv'

nr_of_enties = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [np.random.rand(nr_of_enties), np.random.rand(nr_of_enties), np.random.rand(nr_of_enties)]})
df.to_csv(test_output, index=False)

df_from_disk = pd.read_csv(test_output)

print(df_from_disk['values'][0])

df_from_disk['values'][0]
```

The output from this is something like this:

```
[0.16694782 0.91397397 0.82408103 0.33238402 0.68250766 0.35244128
 0.65239677 0.14443577 0.21036438 0.89503872 0.94680174 0.05199295
 0.7173712  0.35563689 0.19511081 0.14630955 0.46714164 0.56899985
 0.68726772 0.7407746 ]
'[0.16694782 0.91397397 0.82408103 0.33238402 0.68250766 0.35244128\n 0.65239677 0.14443577 0.21036438 0.89503872 0.94680174 0.05199295\n 0.7173712  0.35563689 0.19511081 0.14630955 0.46714164 0.56899985\n 0.68726772 0.7407746 ]'
```

So it is adding `\n` after a fixed number of characters. How can I turn off this behavior, so that all values of the array are on the same line?

Comment: Have you looked at the CSV file?  I can't imagine that's what you want.  Don't you really one a file with 20 columns, as opposed to 1 column with a string representation of a numpy array?  What's happening here is that your dataframe has one column of type object.  When that gets written to file, pandas doesn't see any numbers, so it goes through the default numpy conversion to string, which is designed for pretty printing.  That's what you see.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the comment. I understand your concern. This is a minimal example. In reality the column with 1D arrays represents intensity profiles that I obtain for each sample/row. Each row alsot contains multiple other scalar values as well. I realize that storing data like this is not tidy, but I think it is the best way for what I want to achieve (which is outputting the data so that a colleague can read it from R). (I am open for better alternatives ...)

Comment: @TimRoberts Regarding your comment: `... it goes through the default numpy conversion to string, which is designed for pretty printing. That's what you see.` ,,, Is it possible to overwrite the pretty-printing behavior?

Comment: That's what you give up when you use the pandas convenience functions, like `to_csv`.  If you need finer control over the output, then you have to do it yourself.  That wouldn't be hard here, by iterating through the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this alternative:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
test_output = 'test.csv'

nr_of_enties = 20
data = [np.random.rand(nr_of_enties), np.random.rand(nr_of_enties), np.random.rand(nr_of_enties)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(test_output, index=False)

df_from_disk = pd.read_csv(test_output)

print(df_from_disk.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
0     0.314514
1     0.553836
2     0.604843
3     0.979892
4     0.750518
5     0.414432
6     0.863030
7     0.122440
8     0.109711
9     0.564726
10    0.697969
11    0.195404
12    0.213960
13    0.528277
14    0.032047
15    0.815259
16    0.814184
17    0.428651
18    0.806469
19    0.426095
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

And the csv file looks like:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
0.3145136554585791,0.5538356709436838,0.6048429294053228,0.9798921536916434,0.7505181144630092,0.4144320803123738,0.8630295600003749,0.12243977743033241,0.10971134661253845,0.5647255569124531,0.6979686601938376,0.195403547028268,0.21396002451598795,0.5282768776788274,0.03204733557696737,0.8152587555593714,0.8141843169354687,0.42865099162736087,0.8064688260059022,0.426094757569803
0.7842237807413999,0.9936066439891038,0.251728398701096,0.40807814844117707,0.0908006512885795,0.020505480803844844,0.3101235820377496,0.8148814036196753,0.17648464332529656,0.9541429235932438,0.8862935429230752,0.8704731520822012,0.826814894255303,0.23383289769282622,0.33622395359043133,0.9181969954136576,0.23601716271384177,0.7403487827997589,0.33625135253905125,0.9416527309846678
0.1414644729291913,0.27274477387978724,0.8350208986075496,0.6012600520159657,0.5028596470726449,0.5730619814541527,0.960111329049592,0.29151271757696073,0.7229947207208512,0.5817081850005116,0.3197954200699302,0.9850531074312313,0.6857509727785757,0.12419477334993989,0.9917031585294588,0.817450339249035,0.6888062731767891,0.16701697474792743,0.21780408072745983,0.7470315619995684
```